# AD Server Name Change - Locked out

Tags: active-directory

I have changed my AD server's name due to standardisation of client companies naming schemes. However upon doing so, I am met with -> 'The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship.'

I would usually just spend a day on figuring it out but clients are unable to work xD so its a lil urgent. Can anyone assist me with advice/info?

Comment: **I would usually just spend a day on figuring it out but clients are unable to work xD so its a lil urgent** - Adam, don't be one of "those" people who don't reach out to support when it's obviously and clearly justified and warranted. Your clients can't work. This is not the time for posting questions to the internet or trolling Google search results for the fix. Open a support case with Microsoft.

Comment: Your are completely correct, I feel a fool now. Thank you for redirecting me correctly, you sir are a gentleman and a scholar.

Comment: Hopefully you took no offense to my comment. This is one of those scenarios where it doesn't pay to try and "power through" on your own. If a client is unable to work then it's time to reach out to support.

Answer (score 1):

Renaming domain controllers (that's what I'm assuming you mean by "AD server") can be a tricky business, but it's usually safe enough. The only real issues happen when there are other services (such as file shares) running on the same server, which shouldn't be there in the first place, or when some service or application explicitly uses the server's name instead of looking for a DC the proper way.

Make sure you have rebooted your server two times, and that DNS records have been updated.

Comment: I would just add that he must make sure to reboot the clients computer too maybe x2 times too, so that DNS suffix and all the PC info get refreshed correctly.

Comment: Yes DC, sorry. Company terminology. 

I have rebooted multiple times and flushed dns. 
Issue is "The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship"
Cant log into local users either.

Answer (score 0):

Google found.

I suggest in your case you set an alternate name as to the old machine name and reboot.

Step 1: Getting ready. Open a command prompt. ( ...
Step 2: Adding an alternate computer name. SYNTAX : netdom computername  /add: ...
Step 3: Make the new name the primary. ...
Step 4: Reboot the server. ...
Step 5: Check new server name. ...
Step 6: Remove old hostname. ...
Step 7: Paranoia. ...
Step 8: Clean up.

Comment: Hi my guy, "path not found" when trying to add alt pc name
"domain not found" when trying to add domain with same command

Answer (score 0):

Had to manually flush DNS with CMD and restart a few times, added new user with net user to be sure.
Used connectwise so had access to the console without logging in.

Fare well and thank you serverfault community <3